# Different response status with Postman and MockMvc when updating entity with PUT method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit5

I have defined enpoint with @RepositoryRestResource:

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "Entities", path = "Entities", itemResourceRel = "Entity")
public interface EntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Entity> {}
```

Now when I'm executing PUT method against it via Postman I'm getting status 200 OK and response body, but when I'm running integration test locally with MockMVC I'm getting status 204 NO CONTENT.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Tag("IntegrationTest")
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"dev", "test"})
@Testcontainers
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ContextInitializer.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class EntityRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    (...)

    @Test
    void entityTest() {
        // Arrange.
        byte[] content = newEntityJsonFile.getInputStream().readAllBytes();

        // Act.
        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(put("/Entities/1").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).content(content));

        // Assert.
        result.andExpect(status().isNoContent());
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class RestConfigurer implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
    config.exposeIdsFor(Entity.class);

    config.getExposureConfiguration()
        .withItemExposure(
            (metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(
                    HttpMethod.DELETE, HttpMethod.PATCH, HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.POST))
        .withCollectionExposure(
            (metadata, httpMethods) ->
                httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.DELETE, HttpMethod.PATCH, HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.POST));

    (...)

    config.getExposureConfiguration()
          .forDomainType(Entity.class)
          .withItemExposure((metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.enable(HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.POST))
          .withCollectionExposure((metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.enable(HttpMethod.PUT, HttpMethod.POST));
```